# Render 3D Surface in Python from Blender Exported Mesh

Tags: python, python-3.x, 3d, editor, blender

Is there an existing package to do the above so that 3D objects can be created through a GUI and exported to mesh for use in Python packages?

The link here contains the procedure for exporting the mesh:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Python_Scripting/Export_scripts

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is called blender. Using python you can tell blender to [render a specific frame](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.render), you can also tell it to [render a viewport preview](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.opengl) using opengl. A python script can be generated on the fly and given as a [cli argument](https://www.blender.org/manual/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) for blender to run without using a GUI, [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8405/935) provides an example of passing arguments from the cli to be used within the script inside blender, the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) can be used as a cli equivalent. There is also an option to [build blender as a python module](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) that can be imported in any python interpreter.

To manually render a live 3D view of your model within your app you could use one of several modules that provides opengl support in python to draw the surface, such as [PyOpenGL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyOpenGL) or [pyglet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyglet)